# Cómo hacer petición POST con CURL para obtener datos de una pagina web

Tags: php, webservice, post, php5, curl

Estoy tratando de obtener datos de una pagina web por curl, esta pagina posee un formulario donde se ingresa el id de una persona y al presionar el botón de submit devuelve información como nombre y apellido de la persona. Es obviamente una pagina publica a la que cualquier persona tiene acceso. 
El caso es que el formulario se envia por POST, cuando intento ejecutar el codigo que tengo para intentar obtener los datos lo que me arroja es un error "ERROR 404 Objeto no localizado".

Primero me aparece esta vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego hace una re-dirección automáticamente y me aparece la pantalla de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando hacer esto desde mi local(no se si sea eso lo que no me esta permitiendo obtener el resultado deseado).

Aqui dejo el codigo que he creado:

```
         // abrimos la sesión cURL
            $ch = curl_init();

            // definimos la URL a la que hacemos la petición
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"www.buscardatos.com/Personas/DNI/dni.php");
            // indicamos el tipo de petición: POST
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            // definimos cada uno de los parámetros
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "DNI=aqui_va_el_valor");

            // recibimos la respuesta y la guardamos en una variable
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $remote_server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

            // cerramos la sesión cURL
            curl_close ($ch);

            // hacemos lo que queramos con los datos recibidos
            // por ejemplo, los mostramos
            print_r($remote_server_output);
```

Quiero que por lo menos se muestre en pantalla la pagina de respuesta donde se visualizan los datos extraidos. Pero ni eso. solo me muestra la pagina de error 404 Objeto No Localizado.
No se qué exactamente estoy haciendo mal en el codigo, no se si el problema es que lo estoy haciendo en local. 
Pueden acceder a esta pagina: www.buscardatos.com/Personas/DNI en la cual se ubica el formulario donde se introduce el dni y al darle click al boton submit redirige a la pagina: www.buscardatos.com/Personas/DNI/dni.php en la cual se muestran los datos.

Si pudieran darme una sugerencia o ayuda para aclarar esta duda.?

Comment: Creo que no va a ser posible que logres traer los datos con CURL, el sitio tiene un sistema de protección que tocaría primero determines como poder saltarlo

Comment: mmmm...entiendo. Investigare como hacerlo.